# recommend an opensource message queue service

Tags: jms, message-queue, zeromq, gearman, mq

Can anyone recommend an opensource message queue for me? like JMS, gearmand,zeroMq,Amazon SQS.
Tt would be best to satisfied the following points(not compulsive):

1. distributed and scalable.
2. supported Asynchronous message.
3. best to support pub/subscribe
4. high availability，best never drop message.
5. high performance
6. best to support php sdk, and the mq server developed by c/c++.
7. easy to use
8. the project is active.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the appropriate forum for this question.

Answer (score 5):

Classic brokers:

- **Apache ActiveMQ** — it's a JMS broker implementation from Apache. Written in Java.
- **RabbitMQ** — popular AMQP broker implementation written in Erlang.
- **StormMQ** — AMQP broker written in Java. Drop-in replacement for RabbitMQ (does not require changing clients).
- **Apache Qpid** — AMQP broker, another alternative to RabbitMQ. Written in Java and C++.

Above also provide HTTP (REST API), XMPP and STOMP transports.

Other stuff:

- **ZeroMQ** — this is not a broker, but a library. Allows for either [brokered or broker-less architectures](http://www.zeromq.org/whitepapers:brokerless). Very light, very versatile and very fast. Written in C++.
- **Amazon SQS** — lacks features of others. Awkward limitations like messages are not guaranteed to be in order nor to be delivered only once. No pub/sub architecture. Limited to be used in combination with AWS. Rather high latency.

---

> 1. distributed and scalable. — **all of above**
> 2. supported Asynchronous message. — **all of above**
> 3. best to support pub/subscribe — **all except SQS**
> 4. high availability，best never drop message. — **all, some depending on settings**
> 5. high performance — **all in term of throughput, some less in terms of latency**
> 6. best to support php sdk, — **all of above**, *PHP has [AMQP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php) and [STOMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stomp.php) clients built in, [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php) and [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) have specific bindings.* 
>    and the mq server developed by c/c++ —  **only ZeroMQ, but it's not really a server**
> 7. easy to use  — **all of above**
> 8. the project is active.  — **all of above**

Comment: (+1) I'd also add Apache's QPid to the 'Classic Broker' section, which is an alternate to RabbitMQ (AMQP). For the OP I really recommend you look at either RabbitMQ, QPid or ZeroMQ. I personally spend a lot of time in the messaging space (you'd might say it's my specialty) and I tend to avoid JMS or any other 'lock-in' solutions, favoring AMQP-based solutions instead.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ fits the bill. But it's not c++

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ is the best one. There also support for C++...Refer [CMS](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/)